# C++ circular linked list deletion, counts start at the next node

Tags: c++, circular-list

I have no idea how to delete in a circular link list. For example the head was B, so the list will go  from "B, C, D, E, A". The first node will always pick a number from 1-5 which I keep reducing using the counter, so for example if "B" picked 3, the count will start unto it's next node which is "C" so counting from "C", we will have to eliminate "E", once "E" was eliminated.

The new head aka the picker will start unto the next node after the eliminated node, so the next set of nodes will become "A,B,C,D", this function must repeat until there is only 1 last standing node.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/*
* Node Declaration
*/
struct node
{
    string name;
    struct node *next;
};

node *t, *head;
node *ex;
int paper;
int ctr = 5;
int num;

void create(string sname)
{
    node *n = new node;
    n->name = sname;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = n;
        t = n;
    }
    else
    {
        t->next = n; // connects the nodes
        t = t->next; // moves the connecter to the t= last
    }
    t->next = head;
}


/*
* Deletion of element from the list
*/
void delete_element(string value)
{
}

//Display Circular Link List

void display()
{
    node *temp = new node;
    temp = head;

    if ((head == NULL) && (t == NULL))
    {
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        cout << temp->name << "\n";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void firstpic()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    paper = rand() % 5 + 1;
    int fctr = 5;
    bool p1 = 0, p2 = 0, p3 = 0, p4 = 0, p5 = 0;

    if (paper == 1)
    {
        create("A");//1
        fctr--;
    }
    else if (paper == 2)
    {
        create("B");//2
        p2 = 1;
    }
    else if (paper == 3)
    {
        create("C");//2
        p3 = 1;
    }
    else if (paper == 4)
    {
        create("D");//2
        p4 = 1;
    }
    else if (paper == 5)
    {
        create("E");//2
        p5 = 1;
    }

    if (p1) 
    {
        create("B");
        create("C");
        create("D");
        create("E");
    }
    else if (p2) 
    {
        create("C");
        create("D");
        create("E");
        create("A");
    }
    else if (p3) 
    {
        create("D");
        create("E");
        create("A");
        create("B");
    }
    else if (p4) 
    {
        create("E");
        create("A");
        create("B");
        create("D");
    }
    else if (p5) 
    {
        create("A");
        create("B");
        create("C");
        create("D");
    }
}

void drawn()
{
    node *holder = head;
    ex = holder->next;
    cout << holder->name << " has drawn: " <<num <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    head == NULL;
    t == NULL;
    srand(time(NULL));
    firstpic();
    display();
    num = rand() % ctr + 1;
    drawn();

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Find the node before the one you want to delete, `nodePrev`, and the node after the node you want to delete, `nodeNext`, and then just connect them: `nodePrev->next = nodeNext`. You'll need to verify that you reset your root or `head` if you delete it. Also it usually helps to make these linked lists bi-directional

Comment: example, if my head is (D) and the list goes likes this (D,E,A,B,C) then my tail is (C) right? then D has  drawn 5 so starting from (E) to (D), (D) will be deleted. is the syntax like this, 

Void delpos(int pos)
{
node *prev;
node *next;
 prev = head; // note head is = D
    for(int x =0; x< pos+1; x++) //plus 1 because it should start the count 
                                                  //to the next node
    {
     prev = prev->next;
    }
     next = prev->next;
}

is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may suit your needs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/*
* Node Declaration
*/
struct node
{
    string name;
    struct node *next;
};

node *tail, *head;

void addNode(string sname)
{
    node *n = new node;
    n->name = sname;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = n;
        tail = n;
    } else {
        tail->next = n;    // connects the nodes
        tail = tail->next; // moves the connecter to the t= last
    }
    tail->next = head;
}


/*
* Deletion of element from the list
*/
void removeNode(string value)
{
    // no elements
    if (head == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    node *n = head;
    node *prev = tail;

    // 1 element
    if(n == prev) {
        if(n->name == value) {
            delete n;
            head = tail = NULL;
        }
        return;
    }

    bool found = false;
    // search
    do {
        if(n->name == value) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        prev = n;
        n = n->next;
    } while (n != head);

    // no such element
    if(!found) {
        return;
    }

    prev->next = n->next;
    if(n == head) {
        head = n->next;
    } else if(n == tail) {
        tail = prev;
    }
    delete n;
}

void displayList()
{
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "empty!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    node *n = head;

    do {
        cout << n->name << "\n";
        n = n->next;
    } while (n != head);
    cout << endl;
}

void createList()
{
    const int count = 5;
    std::string names[count] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};

    int nameIndex = rand() % count;

    for(int i = 0; i<count; ++i) {
        nameIndex += 1;
        nameIndex %= count;
        addNode(names[nameIndex]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

    createList();
    displayList();
    removeNode("A");
    displayList();
    removeNode("A");
    displayList();
    removeNode("E");
    displayList();
    removeNode("B");
    displayList();
    removeNode("C");
    displayList();
    removeNode("D");
    displayList();

    system("pause>nul");

    return 0;
}
```

Note that during node deletion you should take care of such cases as:

- No elements case
- Last 1 element to be deleted
- Head deletion
- Tail deletion

Also, never do things like you did in your `firstpic()` function: it is a painfull way to do it. `drawn()` function seems not to do anything that makes sence, but it is out of question's scope.

Comment: omg you are a godsend, I will study this codes, thank you verymuch, I really appreciate it <3 god bless thank you.